# Query of Tasks for Custom Object

Tags: soql, custom-object, tasks

I have a list of Custom Objects, created by customers each day - they can be considered like trouble tickets. Against each one, is a Task created when our agents make an outbound call back to the person. This is through the Salesforce Phone CTI.

I want to list each NEW Custom Object record crated TODAY, and list beside each record:
Blank if no tasks done (ie no one called the customer)
Username and call time if a call has been made

I have the following:

```
SELECT Id, Owner.Name, Subject
from Task
where Whatid in (SELECT Id 
FROM Registration_Object__c 
WHERE (CreatedDate = TODAY)
AND RecordType.Name = 'Media Registration')
```

which lists the details I want, but its limited to only those Media Registrations that have a task associated (ie the ones with no task yet aren't listed with blanks)

In SQL its a join that would do it but I'm new to SOQL, so can't figure out the relationship for the query, or if maybe it needs to be 2 queries.

I've tried a few permutations of

```
Select id, Tenant_Name__c, Tenant_Phone1__c, (SELECT Id, Owner.Name, Subject from Task)
FROM Registration_Object__c 
WHERE (CreatedDate = TODAY
AND RecordType.Name = 'Media Registration')
```

which I know is wrong.

I should have the subquery related back to the Id from the main Select in some format such as:

```
...where WhatId in (the Id from the main query)
```

Or should I do it as 2 queries? (pull all Ids created Today, then pull all Tasks with a WhatId in that list?)

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

If you use the [Child Relationship Name](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_understanding.htm) `Tasks` you should be able to do it in one query.

Example using Account:

`SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, Subject FROM Tasks) FROM Account WHERE CreatedDate = TODAY`

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with the second query you make

```
Select id, Tenant_Name__c, Tenant_Phone1__c, (SELECT Id, Owner.Name, Subject from Tasks)
FROM Registration_Object__c 
WHERE (CreatedDate = TODAY
AND RecordType.Name = 'Media Registration')
```

If we assign the query to list of Registration_Object__c we can show the list of Registration records and either a blank or list of task records as below

```
<apex:repeat value="{!listRegistration}" var="reg">
    <apex:outputText value="{!reg.Tenant_Name__c}"/>
    <apex:repeat value="{!reg.Task}" var="t" rendered="{!IF(reg.Task != NULL && reg.Task.size > 0,true,false)}">
        <apex:outputText value="{!t.Owner.Name}"/>
        <apex:outputText value="{!t.Subject}"/>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:repeat>
```

Hope it helps.