# Custom Object Nested Query on Standard Object

Tags: soql, query, custom, object, nested

Is it possible to do a custom object nested query on a standard object?

Like so:

```
[SELECT (SELECT Id, Case__c FROM Accounting_Instructions__c WHERE Accounting_Complete__c = TRUE AND Case__r.Id =:currentPageId), AccountId, CaseNumber FROM Case WHERE AccountId = :strAccountId AND Id IN :accountIds];
```

There is a relationship between Accounting_Instructions__c and Case (similar to Task and Case). I know you can do two standard objects and use the [relationship name](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_understanding.htm). An example of this is in this post: [Query of Tasks for Custom Object](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/90366/query-of-tasks-for-custom-object).

Because of this format my initial thought would be to change `Accounting_Instructions__c` to  `Accounting_Instructions` (like Task to Tasks) but this doesn't make sense because it's a custom object so I have no idea how Salesforce would understand this naming convention.

All of the documentation I am finding is examples of standard to standard object or custom to custom objects. Any advice?

Comment: See [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/31064) that explains more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the relationship name by running a script like this one:

```
for (ChildRelationship relation : SObjectType.Case.getChildRelationships())
    if (relation.getChildSObject() == MyObject__c.sObjectType)
        system.debug(relation.getRelationshipName());
```

Custom object child relationships end in `__r`. So the likely relationship name would be `Accounting_Instructions__r`.

Comment: So, duplicate of [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/135606)?

Comment: thanks guys for the references. Sorry for the dup. I can delete.

Comment: @Olivia No need to delete, [leave it as a signpost](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230/duplicate-question-etiquette-to-delete-or-not-to-delete).

Comment: I just found out why I couldn't do a nested query the way I wanted- our admin changed the Object name from `Payment_Instructions__c` to `Accounting_Instructions__c`. Although the API name in Salesforce appears to be changed, when I did @adrians suggestion I found that  the API name actually did not changing for some reason and is still under `Payment_Instructions__c`. When I update the query to this API name, I am able to do the nested query. `SELECT (SELECT Id FROM Payment_Instructions__r), AccountId, CaseNumber FROM Case WHERE AccountId = :strAccountId` with the correct returned results.

Comment: It's little surprise that whoever changed the API Name forgot to change the Child Relationship Name. It certainly doesn't happen automatically.

Comment: mystery solved. I just told our admin to update this. Thank you!